# How to make user profiles of specific role as public in drupal 7?

Tags: users

I am working on a project and the problem I am facing is,

There are 2 user roles Doctor and Patient.
What I want to accomplish is profile of users with role of "Doctor" is accessible by all including anonymous and profile of users with role "Patient" is accessible by user himself and all the users with role of "Doctor". 
Rest no one can access the profile of "Patient" role.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [Profile2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) module.

> - With profile2 user account settings and user profiles are conceptually
>     different things, e.g. with the "Profile pages" module enabled users
>     get two separate menu links "My account" and "My profile".
> - Profile2 allows for creating multiple profile types, which may be
>     assigned to roles via permissions (e.g. a general profile + a customer
>     profile)
> - **Profile2 supports private profile fields, which are only shown to the
>     user owning the profile and to administrators**

Check out this [Demo video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPbazpRCwP0).

Comment: I think this doesn't make entire user profile public/private.

Comment: I think this will solve the issue i am facing,
But will have to remove all the existing profile fields and recreate them.
But as the project is in initial phase this wont be a problem.
But using these fields in views and in relationships will be a pain.. :P

Comment: read this post, this might help you :)

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31730/how-to-link-profile2-fields-in-views